# Search options are not separated with spaces

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I'm trying to find the design bug questions which are raised by me, those are not yet with status flags, not as duplicate and not closed with the query below:

[`user:me is:q closed:0 duplicate:0 [bug] [design] -[status-*]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aq+closed%3A0+duplicate%3A0+%5Bbug%5D+%5Bdesign%5D+-%5Bstatus-*%5D)

In the result page, for the **search options**, the search criteria are not separated with spaces. In my case the **search options** as

`questions onlynot closednot duplicateuser 312043`

but it should be

`questions only not closed not duplicate user 312043`

> [image: MSE Search Result]

**Update:**

This issue exists in all Stack Exchange sites. Few more samples:

Meta Stack Overflow: [`user:2451726 is:q closed:0 duplicate:0`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2451726+is%3Aq+closed%3A0+duplicate%3A0)

> [image: MSO Search Result]

ELL Meta: [`user:28470 is:q closed:0 duplicate:0`](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A28470+is%3Aq+closed%3A0+duplicate%3A0)

---

**Update on Feb 06**

Looks like the space between "result found" and "search options" isn't fixed yet. Can this too be taking care?

Sample query: [`user:312043 is:q closed:0 duplicate:0`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A312043++is%3Aq+closed%3A0+duplicate%3A0)

> [image: issue exist]

Comment: Also raised in [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362263/no-space-between-search-options)

Comment: Confirmed - working on a fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just needed some space :) Should be fixed now.

Comment: There is one more issue exist, can you please see my **update** section

Comment: @Arulkumar confirmed - getting to that now

Comment: Looks like the space before "search options" is fixed.